# Binding an event to $(document) inside an angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, document

I have a directive which implements kind of a select box.
Now when the select box is open and I click somewhere outside of it(anywhere else in the document) I need it to collapse.

This JQuery code works inside my directive, but I want to do it "the angular way":

```
  $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
       var $clicked = e.target;
       if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("myClass")) {
            scope.colapse();
       }
  });
```

I tried doing thing with injecting the $document service into my directive but didn't succeed.

Comment: Could you please provide jsifddle/plunker?

Comment: Actually you write directives when you want to play with /manipulate DOM. So I guess attaching above event handler in your directive is the correct way or rather Angular way of doing such things

Comment: Can you show how did you do it and what was the error?

Comment: You can inject `$window` which has onclick functions.

Comment: I didn't have any problems. I was looking for the best practice solution as Yuriy Rozhovetskiy gave.

Comment: See here for Angular2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe, the most true Angular way is to use `angular.element` instead of `jQuery` and accessing `window.document` via the `$document` service:

```
(function() {

  angular.module('myApp').directive('myDocumentClick', 
    ['$window', '$document', '$log',
    function($window, $document, $log) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $document.bind('click', function(event) {
            $log.info(event);
            if (angular.element(event.target).hasClass('myClass')) {
              $window.alert('Foo!');
            }
          })
        }
      };
    }
  ]);

})();
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBdfMLp9mIBhZR9E4wXo?p=preview)