# Angular 2 dynamic component click event

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I'm trying to create components dynamically but i want to add a click action to it and i don't know how. I was trying to do this:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    this.lastSelectedResource = this.defaultImage;
  }

  public createNew() {
    this.container.detach(0);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    let widgetFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CreateComponent);
    let widgetReference = this.container.createComponent(widgetFactory);
    widgetReference.instance.click = this.createNew;
  }
```

but isn't the way do that. Anybody knows how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the renderer and use

```
this.renderer.listen(widgetReference.location.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => { this.createNew(e);});
```

Similar to [Angular2 - catch/subscribe to (click) event in dynamically added HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116770/angular2-catch-subscribe-to-click-event-in-dynamically-added-html/36116838#36116838)

(`widgetReference.location` provides the `ElementRef`)

Comment: Thanks u, this is the solution that i was looking for! :D