# Need to add onclick event on the dynamic html content i am receiving from the api -angular5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, angular5

My angular5 project receives a full set of HTML content from the API side and I am displaying it as it is.Now, After it loads, I need to select some div elements where on its onClick it will apply selection box around that specific div.I am not able to inject the click event from the typescript file.Can anyone help with this?
Below is the code I used to render the HTML to view.
Thanks in advance.

```
       import {Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform, ElementRef, Renderer2} 
        from '@angular/core';
        import {SurveyFormPreviewService} from './survey-form-preview.service';
        import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

       @Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
        export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
            constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}
           transform(value) {
                console.log(this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value))
                return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
           }
       }

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-survey-form-preview',
        template: '<div [innerHTML]="htmlString | safeHtml"></div>',
        styleUrls: ['./survey-form-preview.component.css']
    })
export class SurveyFormPreviewComponent implements OnInit {
    htmlString: SafeHtmlPipe;

    constructor(private surveyFormPreview: SurveyFormPreviewService, private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer2, private elRef: ElementRef
    ) {
        this.getSurveyFormPreview(1);
    }

    getSurveyFormPreview(surveyId: number): void {
        surveyId = 5;
        this.surveyFormPreview.getPreview(surveyId)
            .subscribe(
            resp => {
                this.htmlString = resp["html"];

            },
            error => console.log(error));
    }
```

Comment: You can use `ReadyState` to know when all the data has loaded and then you can use `jquery`to click on that `DIV`.

Comment: Please show some code. Does your API have to return HTML? Usually when using Angular you want your webservice to return JSON data and display HTML client-side.

Comment: possible duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692780/how-to-add-click-event-to-dynamically-added-html-element-in-typescript)

Comment: @Jeto yes, I get a full set of HTML code as JSON data.I need to render a page from it and inject some functionalities to it.

Comment: @fatemefazli actually I have tried it with query selector 'this .elRef.nativeElement' returns the HTML content but using query selector it shows null. I have used the 'class' to identify the div.

Comment: I think the problem is I am receiving full HTML content so when I assign inner HTML to the div, the content will start with the <html> tag again inside that div, That's why I am not able no select the div inside the HTML content.Still, I don't have any solution to how I do it.