# How to bind a click event/function in innerHTML Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml

I have an innerHTML as below:

```
getWidgetItem(widgetId: any) {
      this._widgetId = widgetId;
      this.widgets = [{'name': 'Welcome'}, {'name': 'Welcome1'}, {'name': 'Welcome2'}];
      this.newArray = this.widgets.map((obj) => {
        let htmlText = `
          <div>
            <section class="page subpage dashboard dashboard-page" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
                <div class="newDashbaord">
                  <header>
                      <div class="actions">
                          <button class="control-btn borderless close-btn">
                              <span #target class="icon-close action-icon" (click)="RemoveWidget(${obj})"></span>
                          </button>
                      </div>
                      <h1 class="table-heading">${obj.name}</h1>
                  </header>
                    <main>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </section>
          </div>`;
          return htmlText;
      });
  }
```

But the problem is, I cant access the click event from my span.

I have a function call as below:

```
private RemoveWidget(widget:any) {
    if (typeof widget != 'undefined' && typeof this.widgets != 'undefined'){
      console.log('CALLEDe', widget);
      let index: number = this.widgets.indexOf(widget);
      if (index !== -1) {
          this.widgets.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        // console.log('target called', this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('span'));
        this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', (event) => {
            console.log('event called??', event);
            // this.RemoveWidget(event);
        });
  }
```

But am getting a span from my templateUrl. Cant access the span in my innerHTML span. How can I access it?

Comment: Why do you have `click` on `span`. Wrap the `span` in a button and place the click on that

Comment: i tried with button but somehow i cant find my button in my html through inspect element from my browser.

Comment: But thats not the problem here

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to invoke `RemoveWidget` function on a button click from screen. Where exactly are you facing issue with this

Comment: Don't program this way. Angular is not jQuery.

Comment: You can remove `(click)="RemoveWidget(${obj})"` and `#target` from your HTML string because it won't do anything at all. Angular doesn't process HTML added dynamically. `this.elementRef.nativeElement` doesn't replace it because it listens on the component itself which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: But I need to pass the `obj` into my function. So that I can process it..

Comment: Any suggestions Gunter?

Comment: Actually something is really wrong..

Answer (score 1):

You really should use angular's templating engine.

Instead of trying to add the html via script, you could achieve your desired outcome simply with the following in straight html with the use of `*ngFor`.

```
some-file.html

<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
  <section class="page subpage dashboard dashboard-page" style="overflow-y:hidden;">
    <div class="newDashbaord">
      <header>
        <div class="actions">
          <button class="control-btn borderless close-btn">
            <span #target class="icon-close action-icon" (click)="RemoveWidget(widget)"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="table-heading">widget.name</h1>
      </header>
      <main>
      </main>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

> The [NgFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html) directive instantiates a template once per item from an iterable. The context for each instantiated template inherits from the outer context with the given loop variable set to the current item from the iterable.