# Angular2 router: how to navigate to certain path?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I have module that has its routing settings and contains some children modules. How can i navigate to certain routes from some children to parent or to other (sibling) modules?

As i see I could specify a `name` for the route:

```
{ path:'/About', name: 'About',   ... }
```

and then use it:

```
this.router.parent.navigate(['About']);
```

Since `name` is deprecated, do you know how can i reach the same with the latest version of Angular2 router?

Answer (score 2):

simply use

```
this.router.navigate(['/XYZ', params_here]);
```

or if you want to redirect directly to path then  you can also use this

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/XYZ/ABC');
```

`navigateByUrl` accepts simply string

name has been deprecated in the angular2 beta i think, now the routing is working by matching name with the path name

for more info read out here

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html