# Change href to routerLink for dynamically loaded content in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm creating an admin interface for my site where I can write article. In the editor, I can create links that end up as a[href] in the HTML code of the article.

When I load an article and insert its content into the page, links are still using href (as it should) but then it means that even internal links reload the full page and don't use the Angular router.

How could I "compile" the dynamic content to tell angular to transform "href" to "routerLink" ?

Comment: See here for a good workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783788/3651406