# Link to internal route without reload from dynamically injected links with Angular 7

Tags: angular, routes

In my app, I have a mechanism that parses the piece of text before rendering and replaces all the links looking text into the actual links.
This works great; however, even if I am linking to internal route the app reloads.

Here is one of the examples.

in the template:

```
<mat-card-title [innerHtml]="resolveTaskDetailsHtml()"></mat-card-title>
```

Where the resolving function is:

```
public resolveTaskDetailsHtml() {
    return HtmlService.autolinkUrls(escapeHtml(this.details));
  }
```

The outcome of this is the content with replaced url looking strings into actual links.
Also, if the link is internal the url is relative to the app. Example:

```
text http://app.domain/route/123
```

will be replaced with:

```
text <a href="/route/123">http://app.domain/route/123</a>
```

Is it possible to redirect to an internal route with these kinds of generated links? And how?

There is another similar question here [Add element with RouterLink dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310288/add-element-with-routerlink-dynamically), but it does not look like it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `routerLink` directive instead of `href`, href will circumvene the single page nature of Angular and completely reload the page, while Angular prefers you to use the Router and it's routerLink.

```
<a [routerLink]="resolveTaskDetailHtml()">
```

Where `resolveTaskDetailHtml` should now return: `['/', 'route', '123']`

See [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) for more information.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the thinks are part of the text and injected after parsing. At that point they are not evaluated as router link anymore (unless I am missing something)

Answer (score 0):

**Add a Directive**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInnerLink]'
})
export class InnerLinkDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private router: Router) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onClick(e) {
    const href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A' && href) {
      if (href && !href.startsWith('https:') && !href.startsWith('http:')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.router.navigate([href]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<mat-card-title [innerHtml]="resolveTaskDetailsHtml()" appInnerLink></mat-card-title>
```