# Angular 2 event binding use interpolation doesn't work inside template

Tags: angular

I have simple click event binding

```
@Component({template:` <div ({{eventStr}})="do-log()">DoLog</div>`})
export class AppComponent {
    eventStr:string="click";
    do-log(){
        console.log("ckp");
    }
}
```

of course it will work if change `({{eventStr}})`  to `(click)` .I try many way  like `(${eventStr}) ,(eventStr)`. I don't understand ,inside  `(click)="do-log()"` ,this ***click*** is not string or what other type? 
I want to use `eventStr` instead of `click` because I want to change event type dynamic,e.g. swipe.

**Update:**
I  know there are two way `@HostBinding` and `renderer.listen`, but I have different use case and find some way like this: in parent component template like:

```
 <child-cmp eventType="swipe">Swipe</child-cmp><child-cmp eventType="click">Click</child-cmp>
```

and in child component template like:

```
<div><button (eventType)="dosomething_accordingTo_diff_touch_events()"></button></div>
```

of course with `@Input eventType:string`. It doesn't work. I guess if `eventType` is not a string but an event object, in fact `(eventType)==("swipe") or==("click")`, not equal to `(swipe)` or `(click)`. so is there one  way to let `(eventType)==(swipe)` inside template?

Comment: From my understanding, you want to add dynamic event listener to the `div` refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387..

Comment: In event bindings `(eventname)="dosomething"` `(eventname)` has to be static text in the template. You can't read it from some input or set it dynamically in any way like explained in the comment above or the answer below. You have to do it imperatively like explained in the links already provided.

Comment: Understanding Madhu and drewmoore's explaining, and thank all of you. but I still hope someone can explain how angular template work and why we can have dynamic  some variable inside html e.g.'<div id="'+varID+'"></div>' in jquery, if it is proper here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that.

Binding expressions have to be statically analyzable, so you cannot generate them dynamically. Same goes for anchors ([discussion here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581#issuecomment-148786554)).

Comment: A static or read only property on the class should be statically analyzable, no? I want to avoid magic strings and have the ability to provide extra documentation through doc comments.