# Removing EventListener in ngOnDestroy

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following implementation of a directive. How to removeEventListener in this case:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[Enter]"
})
export class Enter implements OnDestroy{
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        let enter = function(event){
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                el.nativeElement.click();
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('keyup', enter , false);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', enter, false); //this line doesn't work because I can't access enter variable here!
    }
}
```

I know I can simply use a global variable here and can access it. But I don't want to store the state of instance in the global variable.

Comment: Why not make it a field on the class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[Enter]"
})
export class Enter implements OnDestroy{
    private enter;
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.enter = function(event){
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                el.nativeElement.click();
                console.log("enter triggered");
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('keyup', this.enter , false);
        console.log("Added event listener");
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.enter, false);
        console.log("Removed event listener"); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
SZ

Comment: As referred above by @jonrsharpe I cannot simply use 'any' there!

Comment: Your answer is what I have used in my codebase! Thanks a lot @ShellZero

Answer (score 28):

I would leverage `@HostListener` decorator to do that:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[Enter]"
})
export class Enter {
  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
  enter(event) {
    if (event.keyCode !== 13) return;
    this.el.nativeElement.click();
  }
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
}
```

The handler will be automatically removed in `ngOnDestroy`.

For other solutions see:

- [How to listen for mousemove event on Document object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389002/how-to-listen-for-mousemove-event-on-document-object-in-angular/46389054#46389054)

Comment: While `@HostListener` works great, it also makes (my) Angular change detection run for the parent component on each key press. Using `Observable.fromEvent(window, 'keydown').subscribe(...)` does not. I guess one could create a decorator to run the decorated method outside of Angular's zone, but I've not tried.

Answer (score 5):

Make it like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: "[Enter]"
})
export class Enter implements OnDestroy{

    private enter: (event: KeyboardEvent) => void;

    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
        this.enter = (event) => {
            if(event.keyCode === 13){
                el.nativeElement.click();
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('keyup',  this.enter , false);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.enter, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: type function to the addEventListener is wrong! cannot pass this.enter like that! Maybe instead of created enter as a Function. It is better to create it as a enter: any; And then reference it as this.enter. That works.

Comment: @Marley you should type it as whatever it is. If you use `any` you might as well just use vanilla ES6.

Comment: But I'm getting the error, that you cannot pass a variable type Function to the EventListener Object

Comment: Thank you @VRPF It helps :)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the "Angular way" is to inject a `Renderer2` dependency and work with that, to abstract away actual DOM manipulation when working on a platform different than browser (e.g. native or server-side rendering).

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082441/540776).

Answer (score 0):

**Working DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZYnlruYQ2HwrQpHZqV9O?p=preview**

**NOTE**: In DEMO, I use **blur event** instead of **ngDestroy**. (which serve the same purpose).
If you type anything in textbox, it will listen to **keyup event** but as you come out from textbox input , **blur event** happens and no further **keyup** will get fired.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
   selector: "[Enter]"
})
export class Enter implements OnDestroy{
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
      var button=el.nativeElement;
      button.addEventListener('keyup',this.error)
    }

    error(event){
      console.log(event);
        //whatsoever
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
          el.nativeElement.click();
      }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        button.removeEventListener('keyup',this.error); 
    }    
}
```