# How to listen for mousemove event on Document object in Angular

Tags: angular

I am implementing dragging functionality into an angular app: http://jsfiddle.net/Jjgmz/1/

Part of it, is to listen for `mousemove` event on a document object.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {});
```

How can I listen for document object inside of a component?

Lets pretend this is the contents of component.html file:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

I am using Angular 4.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

1) Using `@HostListener` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)). This is the prefered method which should be enough most of the time.

```typescript
import {Component, NgModule, HostListener} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event']) 
  onMouseMove(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  ..
}
```

2) Similar to the above, you can also use `(document:event)="handler"` on any DOM element, but the above solution is prefered because the code is cleaner. By using this, it's not immediately obvious from the class that you have a global event listener, and you might add additional ones unnecessarily.

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div (document:mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)" id="box"></div>
  `,
})
export class MyComponent {
  onMouseMove(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

3) The `Renderer` ([docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer)) is a lower-level solution; useful when you do not want to clutter your code with methods, but deal with the even elsewhere, for example in a hook, as the following snippet shows. Be careful, though, as you still need to remove the event listener to prevent memory leaks; either do this when you know you won't need it anymore, or in the OnDestroy hook.

```typescript
import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  globalListenFunc: Function;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.globalListenFunc = this.renderer.listen('document', 'mousemove', e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // remove listener
    this.globalListenFunc();
  }
}
```

4) Alternative of the first example is a **host property**, which is discouraged by the Angular Style Guide, since you now keep track of the function name in two places which can be very far apart physically in code. Prefer the first version whenever possible.

```typescript
@Component({
  ...
  host: {
    '(document:mousemove)': 'onMouseMove($event)'
  }
})
export class MyComponent {
  onMouseMove(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

5) A reactive way, which Angular embraces, is using `Observable.fromEvent`. This gives you a benefit of all [RxJS operators](http://rxmarbles.com/) for transforming the stream before executing a function. Be careful, though, as you need to unsubscribe manually to avoid memory leaks (unless you subscribe directly in the template using `async` pipe; this will handle unsubscription for you). Also don't forget to add-import the operator, as shown in the following snippet.

```typescript
import { Subscription, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = 
         fromEvent(document, 'mousemove')
                           .subscribe(e => {
                             console.log(e);
                           });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

6) Of course, `document.addEventListener` is always a solution as well; but this is not an intended usage in Angular apps; you should choose different ways. Directly accessing DOM is discouraged as it breaks Angular's neat encapsulation of DOM manipulation. Also you could run into problems with Universal and SSR.

Comment: You should write a book.

Comment: you two should write a book :D

Comment: Thanks for adding all the possibilities.

Comment: in case anyone is wondering you can listen to custom events as well, I was looking for something like this on a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753167/is-it-possible-for-external-files-to-talk-to-angular-5-modules-or-components

Comment: Really great explanation. Just curious, what are my options if I want to unsubscribe from HostListener? I'd like to use the preferred angular method but it seems without an option to unsubscribe, a memory leak could happen and I don't see any information about it being taken care of automatically

Comment: Be careful with solution 1 as it will trigger the changeDetector of your whole application everytime the event is captured, not what your want in my opinion.

Comment: In the last solution, when using RxJS 6, you need to omit the Observable and just use fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').....

Comment: how to listen to this event on the specific element (not on document)?

Comment: for 5) solution I would precised the type of event returned by using the generic of rxjs operator : fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove')

Comment: @albanx change `@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])` to `@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])`

Comment: @paul your solution add an event listener to the whole component, not to an specific element.

Comment: The second solution is BRILLIANT. Thank you, so simple and effective!