# How to remove EventListeners in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to remove the wheel eventlistener immediately after it fired. I tried the following but its not removing the eventlistener.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
       document.querySelector("#section-one").addEventListener("wheel", () => this.myFunction1(), true);
    }

    myFunction1() {
      alert();
      document.querySelector("#section-one").removeEventListener("wheel", this.myFunction1, true);
      console.log("Done!");
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener):

> Calling removeEventListener() with arguments that do not identify any
> currently registered EventListener on the EventTarget has no effect.

your code shouldn't work.

Possible fix can be as follows:

```
wheelHandler: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.wheelHandler = this.myFunction1.bind(this);
    document.querySelector("#section-one").addEventListener("wheel", this.wheelHandler, true);
}

myFunction1() {
    alert();
    document.querySelector("#section-one").removeEventListener("wheel", this.wheelHandler, true);
    console.log("Done!");
}
```

where `wheelHandler` is a function referring to the same instance of handler

For more angular way solution see

- [How to listen for mousemove event on Document object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389002/how-to-listen-for-mousemove-event-on-document-object-in-angular/46389054#46389054)

But AFAIK `useCapture` parameter is not supported yet. So it's always `false`

Comment: You should be aware,that this is not the _angular way_ of adding and removing event listeners.

Comment: @cyrix I know it. You should be also aware about this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11200

Comment: @yuruzi the comment was towards the OP to keep in mind that this isn't the _angular way_ and should be changed once passive event listeners are supported. Also the `document.querySelector` shouldn't be used, instead use for example `ViewChild` decorator.

Comment: @cyrix It's good suggestion but what if `#section-one` is not part of his component. And looking at his code i see that this code is not intended to support server-side rendering or service worker) And the main question here is how to remove `EventListener` that is caught in capturing phase

Comment: I test it, but I face multiple calls when I visited the component several times, because  removeEventListener not works as I expect. someone has some advice?

Answer (score 8):

You could use the HostListener decorator to bind a event listener, but this only works for the host element. If you want to add and remove a listener for a child element you have to use the [Renderer2.listen](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) method. Which returns a function to remove the event listener.

```
@Component( {
  template: '<div #sectionOne></div>'
})
export class myComponent {
  private _listeners = [];

  @ViewChild('sectionOne')
  public section: ElementRef<any>;

  constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._listeners.push(
      this._renderer.listen(this.section.nativeElement, 'click', this.handler.bind(this))
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._listeners.forEach(fn => fn());
  }

  public handler() {
  }
}
```

> The `useCapture` parameter isn't supported by angular by now. For more information, see this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8866).

Comment: The main thing here is using useCapture parameter. Please add it to your example. But try to not override EventManagerPlugin

Comment: Yes passive event listeners aren't supported by angular by now, i will add a note.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that when you use a class method as a callback function, `this` no longer points to the class in the callback function.

Use this code instead to add your event listener:

```js
document.querySelector("#section-one")
  .addEventListener("wheel", () => this.myFunction1(), true);
```

Note that `this.myFunction1` has become `() => this.myFunction1()`. In other words, I wrapped the name of the callback function inside a lambda.

The code to remove the listener stays the same:

```js
document.querySelector("#section-one").removeEventListener("wheel", this. myFunction1, true);
```

Finally, and most importantly, why are you using event listeners like that? This is definitely NOT the Angular way.

Comment: Error: core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present. This is the error I'm getting.

Comment: My bad. Seems like `removeEventListener()` does take at least 2 params. So you can keep your original code for that one.

Comment: But it didn't provide solution for my problem! What's the angular 4 way to do that? I'm finding only angularjs solution for this problem but not in angular 4.

Comment: Please remain cordial. People on here are helping voluntarily. Also, you never said you were looking for an Angular solution... The Angular way is to create an attribute directive. You can use `@HostListener` to add the listener. AFAIK there is no Angular way to detach the listener but you could set a flag inside the listener to make sure it runs only once. Check out the docs https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the `bind` mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46907785/3708323) by declaring the function as a class property with a big arrow like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.querySelector("#section-one").addEventListener("wheel", this.wheelHandler, true);
}

wheelHandler = () => {
    alert();
    document.querySelector("#section-one").removeEventListener("wheel", this.wheelHandler, true);
    console.log("Done!");
};
```