# Hide Angular material 2 table, specific header and its column

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I just tried to hide an Angular material 2 table `statusid` header and column like following.

```
        <mat-table class="mat-elevation-z1" #table [dataSource]="dataSourceHE">
            <ng-container hidden="hidden" cdkColumnDef="statusid">
                <mat-header-cell hidden="hidden"> Id </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell hidden="hidden"> {{row.statusid}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>
         </mat-table>
```

but this is not working properly. if this possible, how can I do this ?

Answer (score 6):

You simply need to **change Column Map in component**. Adding or removing any key inside it causes the table to show or hide the corresponding column.

**Don't try to use** CSS or HTML solutions like using `hidden` attribute or `display: none;` CSS rule, they turn the code into a dirty and fallible one.

Comment: I believe this answer should've been selected.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create an attribute directive, through this directive we can set the display property of an element.

`showcolumn.directive.ts`:

```ts
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ 
     selector: '[showColumn]' 
})
export class ShowColumnDirective implements AfterViewInit{
    @Input() showInput: string;
    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { 
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.style.display = this.showInput;
    }
}
```

Declare this directive in your app's module or any other module:

```ts
import {ShowColumnDirective} from './showcolumn.directive';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ShowColumnDirective]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now we can use the directive inside our table's html Component:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <mat-header-cell showColumn showInput="none" *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell showColumn showInput="none" *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Here's a demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Woyrb9Yx8b9KU3hv4RsZ?p=preview

Comment: This is overcomplicated - you can even do this: <mat-header-cell style="display: none;" *matHeaderCellDef> Id</mat-header-cell>

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the header row. For example, just one column 'title'

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="title">
   <td *matCellDef="let item" mat-cell>{{item}}</td>
</ng-container> 
<tr matRowDef="let row;columns: ['title'];" mat-row></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get here for angular answer. There it is.
Put this code:
In html (adapt to your code):

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-row>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-footer-row>
```

In the .ts
Make your class implements OnInit e OnDestroy

Declare these methods

```
 isPortrait() {
    return !this.landscape.matches;
  }  
  handlerOrientation: any;
```

landscape = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('on destroy');
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906763/how-to-remove-eventlisteners-in-angular-4
    //https://code.daypilot.org/79036/angular-calendar-detect-orientation-change-landscape-portrait
    this.landscape.removeEventListener("change", this.handlerOrientation, true);
  }

  private onChangeOrientation() {
    console.log('landscape orientation');
  }

 landscape = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077302/angular2-material-table-hide-column
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432533/how-to-detect-if-device-is-desktop-and-or-mobile-and-if-connection-is-wifi-or-n
   getDisplayedColumns() : string[] {
            let exibir = !this.isPortrait();
            return this.displayedColumns.filter(cd => exibir || cd.showMobile).map(cd => cd.def);}
```

Declare the columns this way

```
  displayedColumns = [{ def: 'data', showMobile: true}, { def: 'numero', showMobile: false}];
```

}

In OnInit put this

```
this.handlerOrientation = this.onChangeOrientation.bind(this);
this.landscape.addEventListener("change", this.handlerOrientation, true);
```