# Material UI Table: hide columns on smaller screen sizes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to hide columns in a MUI table on smaller screen sizes. I'm following the documentation exactly but getting wonky results. Wondering if anyone has a solution or a workaround.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp';

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein, price) {
  return {
    name,
    calories,
    fat,
    carbs,
    protein,
    price,
    history: [
      {
        date: '2020-01-05',
        customerId: '11091700',
        amount: 3,
      },
      {
        date: '2020-01-02',
        customerId: 'Anonymous',
        amount: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
}

function Row(props) {
  const { row } = props;
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableRow sx={{ '& > *': { borderBottom: 'unset' }}}>
        <TableCell>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="expand row"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          >
            {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
          {row.name}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right"  sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}>{row.calories}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell style={{ paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0 }} colSpan={6}>
          <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <Box sx={{ margin: 1 }}>
              <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom component="div">
                History
              </Typography>
              <Table size="small" aria-label="purchases">
                <TableHead>
                  <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Date</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">Amount</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">Total price ($)</TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                  {row.history.map((historyRow) => (
                    <TableRow key={historyRow.date}>
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {historyRow.date}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{historyRow.customerId}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">{historyRow.amount}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell align="right">
                        {Math.round(historyRow.amount * row.price * 100) / 100}
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
                </TableBody>
              </Table>
            </Box>
          </Collapse>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

Row.propTypes = {
  row: PropTypes.shape({
    calories: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    carbs: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    fat: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.shape({
        amount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        customerId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      }),
    ).isRequired,
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    protein: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0, 3.99),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3, 4.99),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0, 3.79),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3, 2.5),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9, 1.5),
];

export default function CollapsibleTable() {
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="collapsible table" >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell />
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right" sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' } }}>Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map((row) => (
            <Row key={row.name} row={row} />
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

unfortunately the `sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }` is giving me this result on desktop:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iGd6.png)

It is hiding the rows on smaller screens, but as you can see it is fragmenting the dividers on desktop (and pushing the divider on the column header up a tiny bit).

Comment: Did you try any other value? `block` seems like an odd choice. My first guess would be `table-cell`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace this style:

```
sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }
```

with this style:

```
sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'table-cell' }
```

in both header and body `TableCell` because its default value is `table-cell`.

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-shirley-wom1d4?file=/src/CollapsibleTable.tsx) for a live working example.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet. This didn't work for me but helped me figure out the answer. For anyone wondering it did work when I replaced 'table-cell' with 'revert'

Answer (score 0):

If you get here for angular answer. There it is.
Put this code:
In html (adapt to your code):

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-row>
<mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="getDisplayedColumns()"></mat-footer-row>
```

In the .ts
Make your class implements OnInit e OnDestroy

Declare these methods

```
 isPortrait() {
    return !this.landscape.matches;
  }  
  handlerOrientation: any;
```

//https://code.daypilot.org/79036/angular-calendar-detect-orientation-change-landscape-portrait
landscape = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('on destroy');
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906763/how-to-remove-eventlisteners-in-angular-4
    //https://code.daypilot.org/79036/angular-calendar-detect-orientation-change-landscape-portrait
    this.landscape.removeEventListener("change", this.handlerOrientation, true);
  }

  private onChangeOrientation() {
    console.log('landscape orientation');
  }

  //https://code.daypilot.org/79036/angular-calendar-detect-orientation-change-landscape-portrait
  landscape = window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)");

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077302/angular2-material-table-hide-column
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432533/how-to-detect-if-device-is-desktop-and-or-mobile-and-if-connection-is-wifi-or-n
   getDisplayedColumns() : string[] {
            let exibir = !this.isPortrait();
            return this.displayedColumns.filter(cd => exibir || cd.showMobile).map(cd => cd.def);}
```

Declare the columns this way

```
  displayedColumns = [{ def: 'data', showMobile: true}, { def: 'numero', showMobile: false}];
```

}

In OnInit put this

```
this.handlerOrientation = this.onChangeOrientation.bind(this);
this.landscape.addEventListener("change", this.handlerOrientation, true);
```