# Do Angular has a similar function like window.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have a javascript function like below.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
                document.getElementById('mytoken').value = JSON.parse(event.data);

                var token = JSON.parse(event.data);      

                alert('Received message ' + token.message);
                var mytoken = document.getElementById('mytoken');
                mytoken.value = token.message;
                }, false);
```

I'd like to use this script in Angular 5, of course, I am trying to find the proper solution for Angular 5.
Thanks

Comment: You can use this function in angular

Answer (score 7):

In Angular you can use `HostListener` in some component like:

```
@HostListener('window:message', ['$event'])
onMessage(event) {
  ...
}
```

For alternative options see:

- [How to listen for mousemove event on Document object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389002/how-to-listen-for-mousemove-event-on-document-object-in-angular/46389054#46389054)

Answer (score 5):

**Using the HostListener Decorator**

Personally my preferred way of doing it

```
    import {HostListener, KeyboardEvent} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({...})
    export class MyComponent {

    @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event'])
    onKeyUp(ev:KeyboardEvent) {
      // do something meaningful with it
      console.log(`The user just pressed ${ev.key}!`);
     }
    }
```