# Move text along cursor on hovered div

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div I want to hover, **as soon as it's hovered I want to show a text that moves with the cursor but solely on the y-axis.** You can find the effect I'm talking about [on this website](http://juliecristobal.com/) hovering an image.

My code so far:

```
<div class="scroll-container align-self-center">
    <div class="cart-container" *ngFor="let cart of carts; let i = index" routerLink="project/{{cart.title}}">
      <div class="cart-item cursor-hover position-relative d-flex justify-content-center" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + cart.image + ')'}" [class.cart-item-even]="i % 2 !== 0"
      (mouseenter)="cartHovered(i)" (mouseleave)="cartLeft()">
        <h1 class="hover-title" [style.display]="i === hoveredCart ? 'block' : 'none'">{{cart.title}}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

TypeScript:
cartHovered(i) {
  this.backgroundColor = this.carts[i].backgroundColor;
  this.hoveredCart = i;
}

cartLeft() 
  this.hoveredCart = -1;
}
```

How can I achieve this effect using Angular when hovering `.cart-item`?

Comment: Here is a good example for mouse move event.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389002/how-to-listen-for-mousemove-event-on-document-object-in-angular
and then you just need to set the style of your box. absolute position and the x axis to whatever the mouse event gives you

Answer (score 2):

```
<h1 #floatingElement clas=...
--------------------------------
import {fromEvent} from 'rxjs';
....
@ViewChildren('floatingElement') floatingElements;
constructor(ngZone: NgZone){}
ngOnInit() {
  this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
     fromEvent(window, 'mousemove').pipe(
       filter(() => this.hoveredCard != -1),
     ).subscribe(({clientY}) => this.floatingElements.toArray()[this.hoveredCard].nativeElement
       .style.top = clientY) // <-- offset should be adjusted depending on this cursor Y

  })
}
```

angular thing here is ngZone.runOutsideAngular and it is used to stop angular from spamming change detection on every event

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error that says, that `clientY` does not exist on type event.

Comment: subscribe(({clientY}: MouseEvent) => ...) should solve that issue