# Which is better between @HostListener and Renderer.listen?

Tags: angular, listener

I'm building a simple canvas drag n drop application similar to http://rectangleworld.com/demos/SimpleDragging/SimpleDragging. For mouseevent listeners, I used @Hostlistener because for me it has simpler syntax and it is working. There's another way to achieve it with Renderer.listen. But I can't decide to use it over hostlistener. Can anyone explain and tell which is better between `@HostListener` and `Renderer.listen`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer might not be the best but here's what I got.

## **Renderer.listen()**

When it comes to `Renderer.listen()` you need to pass the **`Element`** you want to detect, then the **`Event`** to listen to (`click`, `keydown`, `keyup`, etc.) and finally the **Callback `Function`**

In code, here's what happened in `listen()` function (*):

```
listen(renderElement: any, name: string, callback: Function): Function {
  return this._rootRenderer.eventManager.addEventListener(renderElement, name, decoratePreventDefault(callback));
}
```

So the problem would be now just specifying the `Element` (easy) but people usually use `elementRef.nativeElement` which is a *security risk* according to [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html), so be sure before using it!. Another problem (will not really) is that the `Renderer` class is experimental ([Check its Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html)), I faced a problem with `setText()` it used to work in the RC but now it's not.. so yeah test the `Renderer` functionalities good before using them. aaaaaaand when you're done you need to unbind the event manually!, [Check this answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082441/4341572).

But I would keep an eye on the `Renderer` status because the main purpose of it is rendering the elements on any environment (Web, Node, Mobiles, .etc) with one code base, so yeah let's hope it become stable in the future.

## **@HostListener()**

`HostListener` is a great decorator and shows how great Angular2 works with TypeScript, you only need to set the event and the value to passed to the callback function (the function under it), and usually people just pass `[$event]` so you can have more control on the validations inside the function and YES you don't need to set the `Element` since it listens to the `document` so it's doing a `delegation` to the events and you don't access the `DOM` and your app will be secured. Also you don't need the unbind the events, Angular will do it for you.

[Check this article for a working example](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/)

Hope my answer help, remember Angular is still evolving so some things might change.

References:

*: [Hacking Angular2: Binding Multiple DOM Events by Sean T. Larkin](https://medium.com/@TheLarkInn/hacking-angular2-binding-multiple-dom-events-f781b14ef676#.rtiy8osg5)

Comment: `nativeElement` isn't a problem (security or otherwise) if used with Render2.  See the rest of the warning on the Angular Docs page you linked to.