# Pass external data to Angular-CLI application

Tags: angular

I have an Angular-CLI application (Angular 6) which is being launched from another external page. So at first `index.html` is being displayed. 
I can send data asynchronously from the external page to `index.html` by using `postMessage` method. My question is how to pass this data to my Angular app. I have two problems:

- First one is `main.ts` is launched immediately and by that time I haven't yet received the data sent with `postMessage`. So, ***how can I defer main.ts***?
- Second thing is how to send data to `main.ts` and how to make it available to my application?

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <script>

    window.onload = function () {
      window.parent.postMessage("Loaded", "*");
    }

    window.addEventListener("message",
      function(event) {
        if (event.origin !== 'http://localhost:8080') {
          return;
        }
        console.log("Yes!!!", event.data);
      });

  </script>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

export function getBaseUrl() {
  return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}

const providers = [
  { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] }
];

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: _"how can I defer main.ts"_ Why would you want to defer the execution? You can wait for the message and then bootstrap the application right in main.ts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 window.postmessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444343/angular-2-window-postmessage)