# angular2 regular onclick doesn't update model

Tags: angular

I have a div created in runtime with it's `onclick` bind to a function of the component.

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
div.onclick = this.divClick;
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
```

The click function should update the model like this:

```
divClick(event) {
    this.divContent = event.target.innerHTML;
}
```

but the **view** is not updated with the `divContent` change.
(when logging the value to console it's seems to be updated)

When using the angular's `(click)` it works as expected.

```
<div (click)=divClick($event)>click me</div>
```

I believe the problem is related to the use of the regular `onclick` event, but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take care where `this` points to when `divClick` is called:

Use one of:

```
div.onclick = (e) => this.divClick(e);
```

or

```
div.onclick = this.divClick.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are creating div dynamically, you should bind event to that div dynamically. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2) answer may help you.

Comment: Avoiding direct DOM access doesn't seem to be that much of a priority anymore, from comments I have seen from Angular team members.