# How to trigger a right click event on htmlelement in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, events

I want to do something like this in angular 2(trigger rightclick-event in jquery)

```
('#element').trigger({
 type: 'mousedown',
 which: 3
});
```

just like you can trigger a click event like this

```
var element = <HTMLElement>document.elementFromPoint(corrected_x, corrected_y)
element.click()
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 right click events?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670017/angular-2-right-click-events)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670017/angular-2-right-click-events want to capture the event i want to trigger it on element.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use emenet.click(). See the example where the first button triggers a click event on the second hidden button.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="hiddenBtn.click()">Click hidden button</button>
      <button  #hiddenBtn (click)="hiddenBtnClick()" style="display:none"></button>
      Hidden button clicked: {{times}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  times =0;
  constructor() {
  }

  hiddenBtnClick() {
    this.times++;
  }
}
```