# Is there a way to make right click behave the save way as left click for custom angular components?

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-charts libs, where right clicking on a chart allows user to select a slice of PI, allowing user to generate an event.

```
         <ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
             *ngIf="!histDisabled"
             animations="true"
             [scheme]="scheme"
             showXAxisLabel="true"
             showYAxisLabel="true"
             xAxisLabel="Time"
             yAxisLabe="Counts"
             [results]="histData?.results"
             (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)"
             (select)="onBarSelect($event)"
         >
         </ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

Here, (select) generates a custom object indicating properties of the object in the bar select function. Is there a way to do this with left click?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619887/how-to-handle-right-click-event-in-angular-app

Comment: it doesnt do anything lol. I am trying to capture the context of the right click , that function just suppresses right click options.