# HTML Element with click event to call a function and have anchor tag's context menu in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular6

I would like to have a html element on screen (may or may not be an anchor tag) with a click action to call a function using Angular 6. But the catch here is to get a context menu like an anchor tag does. Example like this:

[image]

I need the first three options. Others are of not much use.

I tried:

```
<a href (click)="someFunction()"> 
<a href="" (click)="someFunction()">
<a href="#" (click)="someFunction()">
```

Click event is not fired for the above ones

```
<a (click)="someFunction()">
```

This doesn't give the context menu the way I need

Comment: what do you mean by `context menu`?

Comment: The menu you get when you right click. Briefly, the image that is posted in the question.

Comment: maybe you do need to track the right-click event and build the menu yourself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41670017/angular-2-right-click-events

Comment: Do you need the native element  that you are selecting or you need the parent element  (menu) ?

Comment: The context menu that comes by default it fine. I don't need the customized one. I just put the screenshot for reference.

Comment: @AbelValdez: Parent element (menu). I mean the normal context menu that you get when you right click on any search result hyperlink from Google search results.