# Kendo Notification UI for Angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

We have to move many components on new Angular 2 and now we have to decide about Notification component: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/notification/index

Will it be migrated on angular 2? will it be ready for first stable release on May 07?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The notification component most probably will not be ready for May.

Comment: But will it be developed in angular 2 one time?

Answer (score 0):

There is no immediate plans for the notification component for the official release as it's stated in the official roadmap:

- http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/

Until an official Notification component is implemented, you can use the Popup component to achieve a similar behavior. The most important functionality (absolute positioning and boundary detection) is already available. With that in mind, you can easily position the popup on element hover:

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
     this.renderer.listenGlobal("document", 'mousemove', e => this.toggle(this.elementOffset(e.target)));
 }
```

Here is a POC demo:

- http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8b4wDrw4k3xzSH8reB?p=preview

P.S. Note that in Angular 4, there will be only `listen` method. More details in this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082441/324224