# Angular click events from component not view

Tags: angular, data-binding, onclick, dom-events

To explain what I'm looking for it's best illustrated the way jQuery works where you can specify a generic HTML element to watch for events:

```
$("label").on("click", function(event){ 
    // do stuff to this element
});
```

Or a traditional addEventListener

```
document.getElementsByTagName('label').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    // do stuff to this element
});
```

I'm surprised to not see this solution all over the internet and instead I see lots of examples on how to use event binding `(click)="clickHandler"` Obviously you wouldn't want to place that handler all over your view.

Can I get some direction/links on how to watch generic events in Angular?

UPDATE:
I appreciate the debate between `@HostListener` listening to the entire DOM, `Renderer2` which will work for specific general elements and apparently the Observable option as well.

Comment: are you looking to attach events dynamically? or do you just prefer to attach events on the JS side? personally, I think the event binding notation in angular's template syntax: `(event)`  is clear and cleaner than doing all the work on the JS side. anyway, you can find what you're looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2

Comment: Maybe if you use the same handler at different place, you can try to make a component

Comment: Hey @AhmedMusallam it seems wrong to apply event binding 20+ times in my view. But `Renderer` looks like the answer, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically add event listener in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2)

Comment: It makes me wonder how big is the view for your component and if you should break it down. Anyway, if that's it, I flagged the question as a duplicate of the one I posted.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Output` format (`(click)=""`) is Angular's wrapper for DOM events (e.g. the example would be for `onclick`). It's important because Angular manages change detection between child and parent components and uses these `@Inputs` and `@Outputs` to do so.

Angular does a lot to work with the DOM api itself and we shouldn't mess with it too much. A lot of times you could get away with a directive or an extended component to handle the behavior.

However, if you wanted to place something globally at runtime, you could inject the `Renderer` into your component:

```
constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) { 
   renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', (event) => {
     // Do something with 'event'
   });
}
```

Note: `Renderer` is marked as depreciated and will be replaced with `Renderer2` with a slightly different API.

Comment: Are you sure angular uses virtual DOM? Can you give a link to support this?

Comment: Upon more research, I might have been mistaken. I was confusing its use of Shadow DOM for styling. I edited my reply, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For a declarative solution if you want a single click handler for the whole document, put this in any component:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onDocumentClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: nice, very interesting

Comment: I've seen this but like the concern of adding many event bindings, what are the implications of importing and using `@HostListener` which apparently listens to the the entire DOM or `Renderer2` which listens to a specific element?

Comment: HostListener attaches only one event listener (for each instance of the component you defined it in). If you want a single event listener for the whole app then put it in a component that only exists once, such as the AppComponent. I think my answer is equivalent to joh04667's answer except that it's a more declarative style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rxjs observables and subscribe to dom events:

```
var button = document.querySelector('button')

Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click')
  .subscribe(
    (event) => console.log(event)
   )
```

Comment: probably not a good idea to recommend adding events or even doing `document.querySelector` unless there is a certain circumstance and that code is in the `AftreViewInit` component lifesycle.

Comment: it's the same thing as referrer with the added benefit of observables

Comment: I'm so tired of Rxjs. It's like using regular expressions. You use it to solve a problem, and then you have two problems.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia lol it def seems that way at first and has a massive learning "cliff" but it's worth it imho.