# How can I pass a reference to an existing callback to @HostListener?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a single callback that I'd like triggered by multiple events. I tried

```
userIsActive(){
  //do something
}
@HostListener('document:mousemove') this.userIsActive;
@HostListener('document:keypress') this.userIsActive;
@...
```

But it doesn't work, `duplicate identifier 'userIsActive'`. I know I can define new functions as callbacks,

```
@HostListener('document:mousemove') foo1(){ userIsActive(); };
@HostListener('document:keypress') foo2(){ userIsActive(); };
@...
```

but creating 2 new functions with arbitrary numbers seems unnecessary and less readable. Is there a way to pass a reference to an existing callback to `@HostListener`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to define multiple methods, you can just decorate the same method multiple times.

For example:

```js
  @HostListener('window:keyup')
  @HostListener('window:keydown')
  handle() {
    console.log('happened')
  }
```

Comment: It technically doesn't answer the question but it's good enough for my purposes. For whoever ends up here in the future, is there a way to reference an existing function or no?

Comment: that is how you reference it multiple times you write it once and decorate it multiple times, or do you mean a function you don't write yourself? Something from another class or library maybe?

Comment: Yes, referencing a function from any import, can it be done?

Comment: maybe using the renderer directly check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2