# Using service to listen for DOM events in Angular

Tags: angular, dom-events

I have a generic pop-up component in my Angular 4 application and in order to correctly handle popup display I need to listen for global click events on the `document`.

There could be many pop-up components at the same time in the application and I need to close them when user clicks somewhere outside of the those components. I shouldn't bind to `document:click` event from the component itself for obvious reasons (there should be only one listener), so I've decided to create a centralized service, which would listen for global DOM events on the document and to command the pop-up components.

When pop-up component is initialized, it registers itself with the service and when it's destroyed it deregisters itself. So, the service always has a list of all pop-up components in the application. So far it works great.

However, I've tried to inject the [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html) to my centralized service in order to listen for DOM events via it's [`listen()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html#!#listen-anchor) method, but it looks like it's only available for component injection, not for service injection.

Also, the `@HostListener('document:click')` decorator is not working in services.

**Is my architecture correct? Is it a bad idea for service to listen for DOM events?**

The other possible solution would be to create another component instead of the service, but I don't like this approach, because it will require it's manual addition to the application somewhere in contrast with service which is automatically created.

**What would be the best way to implement my usage scenario?**

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Observable.fromEvent`

> sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5

Create a service similar to this one:

```
@Injectable()
export class DocService {
  obs: Observable;

  constructor(){
    this.obs = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
  }

  onClick(): Observable{
    return this.obs;
  }
}
```

then subscribe to the observable in your component:

```
// here I just log the event, in your case, you close the popoup
this.docService.onClick().subscribe(console.log, console.log);
```

> you'll probably need to make sure the click is not hapening on your popup. You can handle this is your subscribe method.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, thank you. However, is it better to create a single DOM listener and then translate it using observable to all components, or is it acceptable to just listen for DOM event directly in all components? Is there a performance considerations?

Comment: if there is a performance issue, it's insignificant. unless you have hundreds or thousands of components. I suggest using a service as you'll have only one event-listener and all your components can subscribe to it.