# How to listen to "onFocus" on Angular Material Checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm wondering how to get the following working in Angular 4 and Angular Material: I want to display a little tooltip when the user focusses a Material Checkbox, so I wrote the following in my Template:

```
<mat-checkbox (focus)="foo()">Test</mat-checkbox>
```

In the corresponding component the foo method simply alerts the user (just for testing):

```
sayHello() {
    alert('Hallo Welt');
}
```

It seems that I don't get focus events from the Checkbox this way. The documentation of Material Checkbox tells me:

> The mat-checkbox uses an internal input type="checkbox" to provide an accessible experience. This internal checkbox receives focus and is automatically labelled by the text content of the mat-checkbox element.

So far so good, it seems that the focus event is propagated by the internal checkbox, but how do I have to modify my Template to listen to the focus event?

Btw: I've the same issue when dealing with mat-radio-button

**Update 02.11.2017**
I managed to find a workaround inspired by [Dynamically add event listener in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2). I used Renderer2 to register the deisred listener programmatically like the following:

```
const nativeElement = this.checkboxComponent._inputElement.nativeElement;
this.renderer.listen(nativeElement, 'focus', () => {
  this.tooltip.showTooltip();
});
```

This works but feels unnecessarily complicated, since I have to inject Renderer2 into the component and define a handle to the checkbox component itself via `ViewChild()`.

I can imagine that there must be a much simpler way for this simple usecase?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a late answer but I stumbled upon same problem and while looking for a solution found this issue [1723](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1723).A comment here
talks about the `focusin` and `focusout`.You can have your actions in `focusin`.
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdnvun?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts)

Comment: I found this after about 1hr of searching and trying other ways.
Thanks @kal93