# How to bind an Angular 4 (click) event to a dynamically created div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

The following section of code creates a div block for me.

```js
var addOns = '';
addOns = '<div class="divcl"><i class="fa fa-refresh" id="'+self.data.id+'" (click)="addTab($event)"></i></div>';
return "<div class='node' id='"+this.data.id+"'>"+addOns+"</div>";
```

But it turns out that addTab(event) function is not being recognised by Angular. 
My question is how do I bind an Angular click event to a dynamically created div.

Comment: Don't know much about angular or if things work differently there but in plain javascript you could bind event to the parent of that dynamically created `div` and use event delegation via `event.target`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2

Comment: check out the console log: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pc7ymb

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to create an actual HTMLElement and add an eventListener to it and then use `appendChild` to add it to the DOM.

```
let addOns = document.createElement('div');
addOns.className ="divcl";
addOns.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-refresh" id="'+this.data.id+'"></i>';
this.renderer.listen(addOns, 'click', (event) => {
  this.addTab(event);
})

let node = document.createElement('div');
node.className = 'node';
node.id = this.data.id;
node.appendChild(addOns)

document.querySelector('#stuff').appendChild(node);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7dffje?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts