# Angular - Events () vs Renderer2.listen

Tags: angular

Is it better in Angular 2+ to capture events using () in HTML:

```
<h1 (click)="onClick($event)"></h1>
```

Or using listen method of Renderer2:

```
renderer.listen(element, 'click', (event) => {
  onClick(event);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35082441/8505598  Check that

Comment: @AyaAbdelaziz I already read that, however almost everywhere when we search on the web the first way comes first. If the second way is the best, why the first one exists and why there are fewer resources on that?

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are completely fine. But, in case you need to manipulate the DOM, the safest way of doing it is using the renderer.