# Ionic3 tags like click function are not working in InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, innerhtml

Ionic tags not working in ionic 3. for example (click) method is not working with [innerHTML]. Below is my code.

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
 selector: 'page-html-test',
templateUrl: 'html-test.html',
})
export class detailNewsPage {
html: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
            public navParams: NavParams,
          ) {}
ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.detailNews = `<button ion-button (click)="detailNews1()">Test</button>`;
}
detailNews1(){
 console.log('test-detailNews1 button clicked');
}  
}

**htmlTest.html:**
<ion-content padding> 
 <div [innerHTML]="detailNews | safeHtml"></div>
</ion-content>

**safeHtml.ts**
@Pipe({
 name: 'safeHtml',
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
 /**
  * Takes a value and makes it lowercase.
  */
constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
transform(html) {
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
 }
}
```

Any help, much appreciate

Comment: With `innerHTML`, in angular, the html is **not** compiled through angular, you need to use **ngTemplates**, **ngContainers** and **ngOuterTemplates**. Any html styling or so will work, but anything angular-related will **not** work

Comment: may I know the need of <button ion-button (click)="detailNews1()">Test</button> in component? you can put it in a separate component or directly add html section.

Comment: @PavanShukla the above HTML is coming from server side which I need to bind in my HTML with the help of innerHTML and call the "detailNews1" function which is mentioned in component

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2

Comment: In addition to Pavan's comment, you are looking for a "$compile" equivalent in angular 2+. This can't be directly accomplished, since template compiling in angular 2 was intentionally made more complex. This may help you, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2

Comment: @PavanShukla please share the code to implement with my requirement

Comment: @briosheje please share the code to implement with my requirement

Comment: @Priyank : I wouldn't implement in that way, we usually avoid interpreting server side generated scripts in angular in general, that's not exactly the approach we're used to follow. The closest you can get or try to work with is the example above, you need to work with templates and dynamic components generation, you can't do much more than that, since angular is compiled already at runtime.