# Bind events to dynamically created html in Angular

Tags: angular

In my angular (6) app I am using a charting library that generates the chart and its html after the component is initialized.

I would like to add events (specifically a hover event) when hovering over a certain div. I would normally just use the built in angular `(mouseover)` but since the html is generated by the library, I don't have access to the html to add these things.

How can I add these events after the html is generated?

Comment: Could you tell us which charting library are you using? Some of the code you tried would be very helpful.

Comment: @AntonioGarcía yeah its https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't have access to the dynamically generated HTML the choices you have are two:

1. Fork the library's code and add the event listener. Then use the forked code in your application. I would advise **strongly** against this tho. You would need to maintain another library and this can lead to a lot of errors and a lot of overhead
2. Add an event listener directly to the generated HTML element. This would be a more direct solution without much overhead.

So expanding on 2.:

You would need to use listen from Renderer2 from angular, which is detailed in docs [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) and in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener) as well. In sort you need to create something like this:

```
let global = this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (evt) => {
  console.log('Clicking the document', evt);
})

let simple = this.renderer.listen(this.myButton.nativeElement, 'click', (evt) => {
  console.log('Clicking the button', evt);
});
```

Please also keep in mind that the element should already be rendered for this to work, so you need to place this code either inside the ngAfterViewInit() [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) or set a timeout (not advised - you don't want to have to debug race conditions as well).

As a note, please also see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlspY2h4syQrheWSPASZ?p=preview) of the linked issue to see the full implementation.

Comment: wouldnt I need a view child to use a nativeElement? I cant add the proper tags to the html to use view child

Comment: Yes, something in the lines of "@ViewChild('myButton') myButton;" if you check the plunker attached in the linked issue it shows how it can be done.