# Angular 2 how to update Observables arrays?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript

Stack: `Angular,Nativescript, Typescript`.

I am getting id's from `localStorage` and then for each `id` I am calling `HTTP` request to get that item from `API`. Everything works fine, but I want to make that both (`LocalStorageArray` of id's and Items from `Http` request) would be subscriptions and they would watch for changes. For example: if there are new `localStorage` id, it would call `HTTP` from that id and then add to my `observable array`.

My example works but not as I want, because it isn't updating my `ObservableArray` after I add an item to my `localStorage`. I searched for answers on StackOverflow how to subscribe to the array and call a function every time it changes, but neither helped. Links I viewed :

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-ListView/getting-started

https://appdividend.com/2018/12/08/angular-7-observables-tutorial-with-example/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent

My example :

**Home.component.ts :**

```
data;
    public filteredItems : ObservableArray<Observable> = new ObservableArray([]);
    localStorageArray = [];
```

```
 public getStorageArray(){
     this.localStorageArray = new Array;
        console.log(localStorage.length)
        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            let val = localStorage.getItem(key);
            this.localStorageArray.push(val);
        }
        console.log('Local storage array', this.localStorageArray);
        if(this.localStorageArray.length != 0) {
            this.getFavorites(this.localStorageArray);
        }
    }

    getFavorites(eanArray){
        if(this.localStorageArray.length > 1){
            this.data = this.dataService.getProductsByEan(eanArray).subscribe
            ((data: any) => {
                    this.filteredItems = data['hydra:member'];
                    console.log(this.filteredItems.length);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }, () => {
                console.log('favorites succes')
            });
        }
      }
```

And then I am trying to update `this.filteredItems` from another component :

**List.component.ts :**

```
providers: [HomeComponent],
constructor(private home: HomeComponent){}
```

1.nothing happens, it isnt updating :

```
updatefilteredItems(item){
console.log(this.home.filteredItems.length) --> 0 , but it has items.
this.home.filteredItems.push(item)
console.log(this.home.filteredItems.length) --> 1 , but it has more items.
}
```

2. nothing happens, it isnt updating :

```
updatefilteredItems(){
this.home.getStorageArray();
}
```

I expected that when I update `this.filteredItems` it would update it, but it didn't.

Comment: So why not just subscribing to every id?

Comment: I was trying , but I only know how to subscribe to one value at the time, not the whole localStorage  ,  would you help me to understand how to subscribe to every id ?

Comment: please look here for the 'storage' event:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: I found "Responding to storage changes with the StorageEvent" this topic in your link, but it isn't really explains how to make it with typescript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener

Comment: Note: You cannot provide and inject `component`. Only `services` should be provided and injected.

Comment: Then how to update that observable ? How to call that function which are only in that component ? I understand services and how to use them, but when I have a subscribtion in a component - how to reach it via service ?

Comment: Well, you need a `BehaviorSubject` inside a shared service to achieve that. And then your components will communicate through it by emitting and subscribing. https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc